# How to share audio and video via video-chat software on linux?

Tags: fedora, kde, pulseaudio, video, remote-desktop

Me and my friend are both using Fedoras latest version (at the moment 31) and want to video chat with monitor/sound sharing, so we can watch a movie together.

I've tried several options to meet this demand with limited success:

1. Using Skype (kind of the naive approach) is the worst option because the `share screen with audio` option works only with windows (I've tried it) and I'm having privacy concerns.
2. Next option was to use Jami, which feels way better then skype, but also does not provide some way to share video with audio out of the box.

   1. My next idea was to create some form of pulseaudio rule that maps the input of my microphone and the video player (usually vlc or firefox) into a common device and use this as the basis for jami's audio.
3. In the meantime my friend was looking for a way to stream video/audio via vlc, which has several drawbacks as well. The http stream can be watched by everyone and the buffering makes synchronizing the streams impossible, but the video quality is really nice.

Do you have a idea (or direction) as to how I can share audio and video via a video chat software?

Maybe provide another software with this feature or a idea how to create a pulseaudio rule for mapping the devices.

Comment: Are you wishing to see each others screen, or just the output of camera and microphone?

Comment: Ideally there are two different modes (like in skype): One where you see and hear each other, so you can talk. And the other mode shares the screen of one user with the other user including audio from the running application and the microphone. So you can watch a movie together and still talk to each other about the movie.

Comment: There could be a browser-based solution with modern Firefox. The browser can do it I think.

Comment: Please put amendments into the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some extended web-search I found a wonderful solution to this problem, [pulseaudio-config](https://github.com/toadjaune/pulseaudio-config). Everything needed to solve this problem can be found there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [qpwgraph](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/rncbc/qpwgraph) for [pipewire](https://pipewire.org/), which is a GUI tool, that lets you draw connections within a graph. Where the connections represent the flow of your audio signals, much like in the [image](https://github.com/toadjaune/pulseaudio-config/blob/master/images/simple_schema.jpg) of the git-repo of the first answer.